# Run windows c# application even when screen is locked

Tags: c#, .net

Hello all i am developing a windows application where i am using timer which check system time every second and run my code on specific time which i have hard coded in code.

It works fine when the system is not lot locked. but user is inactive windows gets locked and application stops running and timer gets stop and code doesn't run in that case.

So i just want to know is there any way to keep c# application running even if windows screen is locked..

Note:-i don't want code which keep windows busy and prevent it from locking.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider running it as a Service

Comment: Use a windows service or a windows scheduled task.

Comment: Locked is *not* the same as "logged-out". An application will continue running if the user locks the screen, eg with `Win+L`. It won't run if the user logs out. Only services and scheduled tasks will run without a logged-on user

Comment: There is no good reason for an app to "stop" when the secure desktop is displayed.  You need to use remote debugging to find out what is going on.

Comment: Service should not stop while Window + L (locking screen). You can also use Quartz scheduler.

Comment: how to consider it running as service?